# how to resolve telethon session file sqlite3 database full error?

Tags: sqlite, session, storage, telethon

I am getting an error where sqlite3 DB in the telethon session file in my cloud environment runs out of space stopping my script. I even tried `telegram_client.session.save_entities = False` but still same issue

Comment: can you post the full error ? I have a db with almost ten thousand records and it's just 1.5mb in size

Comment: You can use alternative session backends if you have trouble with SQLite, as described in https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/sessions.html